# Stuck on purple screen.. nomodeset not working

Tags: boot

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Vostro,each time i start my pc it freezes on a purple screen and it doesn't boots and shows me grub menu please help me. I've tried using nomodeset

Comment: Is it a new install or happened after some usage? Did you fsck the disk?

Comment: I've hardly used it for two weeks